# Replace a value in a data frame from a dictionary using a function map

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have values in a df that i would like to replace with values from a dictionary. My issue is that only one value is being replaced and i expect both to be replaced.

```
import pandas as pd
 
d=[['Alabama','English','test@gmail.com']]
df=pd.DataFrame(d,columns=['state','lang','Email'])

replace_dict={
    "state":
        {"Alabama": "AL", "Alaska": "AK"},
        "lang":
        {"English":"ENG", "French":"FR"}}


def replace(df,colname):
    for colname, value in replace_dict.items():
        df[colname] = df[colname].replace(value)
        return df

parsing_map={
"state":[replace],
"lang": [replace]
}

 
for i in parsing_map.keys():
    for j in parsing_map[i]:
        df = j(df,i)
```

the current df from this with return Alabama as AL but it will not return English as ENG.

my desires output is:

```
 state     lang           Email
0    AL     ENG      test@gmail.com
```

Why is this only replacing one of the two values that the parsing map is naming the column name to the replace function and not replacing both values? How do I make the function return both values to the desired output by using the replace_dict to do so?

Answer (score 0):

here is one way to do it

```
# filter replace_dict by state and lang respectively to map the DF

df['state']=df['state'].map(replace_dict['state'])
df['lang']=df['lang'].map(replace_dict['lang'])
df
```

```
    state   lang    Email
0   AL  ENG     test@gmail.com
```

Comment: this does not solve my issue or add anything to the post of use.

Comment: Can you provide more details as to what didn’t work? I tried on what you shared in the question and shared results from it. @githubber

Comment: well im looking to use the function and the parsing map still. I dont want to change all of my code i want the structure of it to be similar but just have my desire output. @naveed